# <?php echo $total; ?> issue

Tags: php, count, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP script not working in HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198680/php-script-not-working-in-html-file)

I have this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $f = fopen('counter.txt', 'r+');
   flock($f, LOCK_EX);
   $total = (int) fread($f, max(1, filesize('counter.txt')));
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      rewind($f);
      fwrite($f, ++$total);
   }
   fclose($f);
}
?>
```

AND it works in the txt file. It counts correctly the clicks. BUT this:

```
Times submited <?php echo $total; ?>.
```

doesn't work in my index.html file where I have my form. Please can you help?

This the line of my files:

1. form (index.html)
2. a .php file
3. header("Location: thankyou.php")
4. then back to index.html

Comment: We'd need more HTML, in my opinion, to help.

Comment: PHP code doesn't (usually) run in `.html` files. And variables such as `$total` do not persist across different page requests; the counter file needs to be read again.

Comment: You can store $total in a cookie or session variable to enable access in any page. Also use .php for it to work

Comment: Yes. I think this might be a scoping problem either within code or across requests (use session). Declare a a global $total if you're not doing it.

Comment: Move index.html to index.php. Then you can do what you need.

Comment: William The Dev is this?     <?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start(); 
 
 // echo variable from the session, we set this on our other page 
 echo "Our color value is ".$_SESSION['color']; 
 echo "Our size value is ".$_SESSION['size']; 
 echo "Our shape value is ".$_SESSION['shape']; 
 echo $total;
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, php isn't going to be executed in an html file. You need to make the file a php one so the server treats it way.

That's why it's working in the text file.

If it has to be html, you can use this:

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Secondly, the $total variable isn't global, so it won't be known in a different php file, you'll either need to pass it using get or post, or include the php in the first html file.

I'd go with the latter.

Comment: Well that makes sense, it's not surprising they don't let you play around d too much with the htaccess file. Try moving the php into the html file and changing it to php from html.

Comment: Do if(! Empty($_post['submit']) {} 
Also, use get not post.

Comment: I am so confused and so newbie in .php....

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of clicks without writing to a file you will need to store the number of clicks in the session because it is not global, nor does it persist beyond a single request.  This would all need to be done in the .php file.

```
<?php
$total = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

1. Read the value from session back into $total before incrementing.

   ```
   if(isset($_SESSION["total"]))
      $total = $_SESSION["total"];
   ```

2  Increment $total

```
  $total++;
```

1. Store $total back into session

   ```
   $_SESSION["total"] = $total;
   }
   ```
2. Then you can print out the total.

   ```
   echo 'Times submited: ' . $total .'.';
   ?>
   ```

Comment: $total = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_SESSION["total"]))
$total = $_SESSION["total"];
$total++;
$_SESSION["total"] = $total;
 }
echo 'Times submited: ' . $total .'.';     **** It didn't work. Still <?php echo $total; ?> doesn't appear in index/html . Thank you very much for your time though.