# xampp - php not being interpreted when part of an html file

Tags: php, xampp

Using xampp and having some problems. When I put a section of php code into its own file with php extension and run that via localhost then it works. When I embed the php into a file with html extension and run that it seems the php is not being interpreted but completely ignored. Is there an xampp config option that disables php being interpreted in javascript or html files?

Comment: You mean you want to enable PHP in html?

Comment: [already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198680/php-script-not-working-in-html-file)

Comment: Thanks @Totoro, I'll vote to close as a dup of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you've got xampp installed in the root of C (the default location)...

I wouldn't really recommend it as it adds an unnecessary overhead on actual HTML files but you can do it ... in `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` you should see something that looks like:

```
#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

You *can* tell Apache to treat .html files as PHP by adding a new FilesMatch directive:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Or you can do it by adding an `.htaccess` file into your document root that contains something like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html`

There are much better ways to do it though, use RESTful URLs for instance (and thereby avoid having the file-type even hinted at) and keep all your PHP files as `.php` - but you'll probably need to get into the dark arts of [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it hasn't helped. I stopped and started apache and mysql and also tried rebooting but it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks you, thank you, thank you, thank you. You got me looking in the right direction. I reinstalled xampp and then made 1 change in c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf in the <IfModule mime_module> section by adding... AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm    NOW IT WORKS!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

when embedding it are you using the tags?

e.g. 
    echo 'Yay';

should be

```
<?php echo 'Yay'; ?>
```

or you could change the extension of the file from HTML to PHP, do you PHP code at the top and html at the bottom